# What does "%hi(__gnu_local_gp)" mean in MIPS assembly?

Tags: mips, disassembly

I'm learning MIPS so I wrote a simple C program and generated MIPS assembly with gcc and inside it there is this part

```
lui     $28,%hi(__gnu_local_gp)
addiu   $28,$28,%lo(__gnu_local_gp)
```

I know that `lui` means *load upper immediate* but I don't know what `%hi(__gnu_local_gp)` and `%lo(__gnu_local_gp)` mean; `addiu` means *add immediate unsigned*.

Are `lo` and `hi` registers?
If so what does `%` mean?

Comment: That instructions just write lower and high words of the constant gnu_local_gp to the immediate register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions load the address of the symbol `__gnu_local_gp` into register 28.
`__gnu_local_gp` is a memory location that is used to store the [Global Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS), and register 28 is typically used to hold the Global Pointer.

'%hi' and '%lo' are builtin functions of the GNU assembler, and have nothing to do with the `hi` and `lo` registers in the MIPS architecture.